# Bind array of complex objects in GET request - jquery.param() traditional flag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I'm trying make a jquery.ajax call to the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult Handler(SemanticPart[] semanticParts, string first, string last)
```

I have the following data JSON object with the corresponding server side model having public { get; set; } properties:

```
 var data = {
      semanticParts: [{ hasLabel: "label", hasType: "type", hasIndex : 0 }],
      first: "first",
      last : "last"                             
 };
```

The problem is [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) seems to have no serialization option for the default MVC model binder.

`decodeURIComponent($.param(data))` produces:

```
 "semanticParts[0][hasLabel]=label&semanticParts[0][hasType]=type&semanticParts[0][hasIndex]=0&first=first&last=last"
```

while setting the `traditional` flag like so `decodeURIComponent($.param(data, true))` produces:

```
 "semanticParts=[object+Object]&first=first&last=last"
```

MVC's default model binder for complex arrays needs the following to bind correctly (tested in Fiddler Composer):

```
 "semanticParts[0].hasLabel=label&semanticParts[0].hasType=type&semanticParts[0].hasIndex=0&first=first&last=last"
```

Which simply used: `array[0].property=` instead of `array[0][property]=`

I understand there's no universal specification for param strings agreed-upon by all web frameworks but why jQuery.param with traditional flag set true returns a  [object+Object] is beyond me... that is absolutely useless in any framework.

It there any way to patch this?

Perhaps a regex to replace the pattern `[#][text]` with `[#].text`? (actually the encoded version of this is more relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a model to hold this parameters:

```
public class SemanticPartViewModel 
{
  public List<SemanticPart> semanticParts { get; set;} 
  public string first { get; set; }
  public string last { get; set;}
}
```

And change the controller to receive this as parameter

```
public ActionResult Handler(SemanticPartViewModel semanticParts)
{
  /*Do stuff*/
}
```

You should use JSON.stringify(mydata) as well to create the data for the $.ajax call

This way the default modelbinder will take care about the rest.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for a GET request. It must remain a GET, which is why I am trying to send data through the URL. 

In MVC Web Api you can use [FromUri] attribute and it will correctly bind. Is there any way to have plain MVC mimic that behavior? [FromUri] does not seem to work in plain Controller's action, only on ApiController action